# Is it possible to connect to a PostgreSQL server using FreeTDS driver and tsql?

Tags: postgresql, odbc, tsql, freetds

Can I make a connection to a PostgreSQL server using FreeTDS, more specifically `tsql` command?

I've been trying for a few days now, using many different configurations. Even though I am able to connect to the DB using `isql` and PostgreSQL odbc driver, I can't to make it work for `tsql` (it also doesn't seem to use `odbc.ini` or `odbcinst.ini`). So, I was wondering if `tsql` only works with MSSQL.

If you want, I can post the files `freetds.conf`, `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini`.

Thanks.

Comment: Good question but probably the wrong site.  Should this be on Stackoverflow?

Comment: @AveryPayne, I thought here was more appropriate. But I'll give it a try over there. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different databases use different network protocols.

`tsql` only works with MS SQL and Sybase. That's actually an exception to the general rule, because they historically came from the same codebase.

For Postgres, you need the command-line client `psql`, or (as you mentioned already) the Postgres ODBC driver, or a program build using the Postgres C client library, or a java program using the Postgres JDBC driver, or a .NET program using the [PGNP OLEDB](http://pgoledb.com/) driver...